# fb_exchange_token parameter not specified facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk

O meu sistema de login com `facebook` funciona apenas e só da primeira vez que o utilizador faz login com o facebook. assim que termino sessão/ reinicio o browser deparo me com um erro

> fb_exchange_token parameter not specified

ou por vezes não recebo o erro mas também não consigo receber os valores do utilizador.

Como é que posso resolver este problema?